# Subscribe inside a subscribe maintaining the order

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Below coding has subscribe inside a subscribe. It gets a schedule_id and according to the schedule_id retrieve questions. This works perfectly but the order of `getQuestion()` is not guaranteed.

> schedule_id#: 111, 222, 333, 444
>
> getQuestion(schedule_id) output#: q1(222), q23(111), q12(444), q15(333)
>
> But it should be#: q23(111), q1(222), q15(333), q12(444)

I need to execute `getQuestion()` according to the order of schedule_ids, wait until one process finishes before go to the next.
Is it possible to use `forkJoin()` here?

```
const source = from(res.data);
source.pipe(map(({ schedule_id }) => schedule_id))
  .pipe(mergeMap(schedule_id => {
    let param = {
      "schedule_id": schedule_id
    }
    console.log("schedule_id#: ", schedule_id);
    return this.fetchApiService.getQuestion(param);
  }))
  .subscribe((result) => {
    console.log('result#:', result);
  })
```

Comment: Try changing `mergeMap` into `concatMap`

Comment: @MrkSef Then it gets only one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ConcatMap works just fine for me. Of course, with concatMap, you will never start the next observable until the previous one completes (that's how you maintain order). If you hand it an observable that never completes, you end up with a minor memory leak and nothing else.

If I take you code and make a lawful observable, it works for me.

```ts
  myConcatMapFunc(){
    let schedule_ids = from(['111','222','333','444']);
    schedule_ids.pipe(
      concatMap(data => {

        let param = {
          "schedule_id": data,
        }

        console.log('schedule_id#', data);

        return new Observable(subscriber => {
          subscriber.next('Q1');
          subscriber.next('Q2');
          subscriber.next('Q3');
          subscriber.complete();
          return { unsubscribe: () => {} };
        });

      })
    ).subscribe(result => {
      console.log('result#', result);
    })
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how to use unsubscribe on my original code which I've mentioned on the question. `const source = from(res.data);
source.pipe(map(({ schedule_id }) => schedule_id))
  .pipe(mergeMap(schedule_id => {
    let param = {
      "schedule_id": schedule_id
    }
    console.log("schedule_id#: ", schedule_id);
    return this.fetchApiService.getQuestion(param);
  }))
  .subscribe((result) => {
    console.log('result#:', result);
  })`

Comment: What you're asking isn't clear to me at all. Maybe update your question or ask a new question with a bit more clarity

Comment: Thanks it's working. I modified my code like below.

`const source = from(res.data);
source.pipe(map(({ schedule_id }) => schedule_id))
  .pipe(mergeMap(schedule_id => {
    let param = {
      "schedule_id": schedule_id
    }
    console.log("schedule_id#: ", schedule_id);
    return this.fetchApiService.getQuestion(param)
 .subscribe((data) => {
        observer.next(data)
        observer.complete()
        return { unsubscribe: () => { } }
      })
  }))
  .subscribe((result) => {
    console.log('result#:', result);
  })`

Answer (score 0):

The operator concatMap() waits for the previous inner observable to complete before commencing the next observable, whereas mergeMap() processes multiple inner observables at the same time, with no guarantee of ordering.

Try this:

```
const source = from(res.data);
source.pipe(map(({ schedule_id }) => schedule_id))
  .pipe(concatMap(schedule_id => {
    let param = {
      "schedule_id": schedule_id
    }
    console.log("schedule_id#: ", schedule_id);
    return this.fetchApiService.getQuestion(param);
  }))
  .subscribe((result) => {
    console.log('result#:', result);
  })
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kxrccs
Please check this link. `concatMap()` retrieves only the first value but `mergeMap()` retrieves all.

Comment: There is a really good example at https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/concatmap which shows the observables streaming  in sequential order using concatMap() .. or am I missing something here?